# Scylla db json support for insert with DEFAULT UNSET directive not working

Tags: scylla

I am trying the following **insert statement** with DEFAULT UNSET directive, but I get syntax error in the statement. I am using scylla 2.3.1. I tried to the syntax in Apache Cassandra and DSE. It works there.

`CREATE TABLE user (id int primary key, name text, email text)`

`INSERT INTO user JSON '{"id": 1, "name": "Sam"}' DEFAULT UNSET`

Following statement works in scylla.
`INSERT INTO user JSON '{"id": 1, "name": "Sam"}';`

I have turned on experimental flag in the scylla.yaml to activate json support.

Comment: A bug has been reported - https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/issues/3909

Answer (score 6):

This bug is now fixed and will be released in a future version of Scylla.

Answer (score 0):

Scylla supports `json` format from v2.3 . This bug is fixed in v3.0 which will be released very soon (Release Candidate 4 - RC4 was already released).
Here is the documentation about json support in Scylla:
https://docs.scylladb.com/getting-started/json/